# How to distinguish nestedlistitemtap on same item name but different parent in Sencha Touch?

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I’ve created a nested list with following structure:

[image]

Now I’m performing different-2 task on these items using ***onNestedlistLeafItemTap*** as follows:

```
if (record.data.text === 'Shop Item')  // Item-1 Shop Item
{
// some line of code
}

 if (record.data.text === 'RIM Item')  // Item-1 RIM Item
{
// some line of code
}

 if (record.data.text === 'My Item')  // Item2- My Item
{
// some line of code
}
```

But problem is here: How can I distinguish which Shop Item is tapped that means ***Item1-> Shop Item*** is tapped or ***Item2-> Shop Item*** is tapped because in both case only first condition is called. 
Let me know how can resolved this problem.

Any help is appreciating!!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `parentNode` on the `record`:

```
if (record.data.text == 'Shop Item' && record.parentNode.data.text == 'Item2')
{
    //some code
}
```